# express-validator: Handling conditional validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I have a form which takes the user email and password. I have setup validation with express validator which checks if the user email and password are empty and if email is a valid email as shown below.

```
const loginSchema = [
  body("email")
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage("email must contain a valid email address")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("please enter email"),
  body("password").notEmpty().withMessage("please enter password"),
];
```

When testing in postman, if a user was to submit the form without entering email and password, it displays all error messages. How do I use conditionals with express validator to make it so that isEmail() withMessage is only called if the request body email is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [express-validator docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/6.13.0/validation-result-api#arrayoptions):

> If the option onlyFirstError is set to true, then only the first error for each field will be included.

So you basically have to do this instead

```
validationResult(req).array({ onlyFirstError: true })
```

Alternatively, you can use the following to have the errors from a request be a map from field path to first error of that field:

```
validationResult(req).mapped()
```